# cocos2d + box2d: How to determine body after a collision?

Tags: iphone, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

If two bodies collide and I get the collision event with this code in my step function:

```
std::vector<b2Body *>toDestroy;
    std::vector<MyContact>::iterator pos;

    for(pos = _contactListener->_contacts.begin();
        pos != _contactListener->_contacts.end(); ++pos) {

        MyContact contact = *pos;

        b2Body *bodyA = contact.fixtureA->GetBody();
        b2Body *bodyB = contact.fixtureB->GetBody();

        if (bodyA->GetUserData() != NULL && bodyB->GetUserData() != NULL) {


        }

    }
```

How do I determine if lets say bodyA hit bodyB and not bodyC?

What is the easiest method for doing this?

Comment: This code tells you bodyA hit bodyB. There is no bodyC here. It's up to you to figure out what to do with this knowledge. If you have assigned a CCNode as the userData() property of the box2D body, you can get it like `CCNode *nodeA = bodyA->GetUserData()` and then do some checking like [nodeA objectType] where objectType is some property that you have defined.

Comment: thx but to make my question simpler: - How can I determine if wall hit the ball, not ball hit ball?

Comment: I just told you, it's in my comment how you would do that.

Comment: thx I get it finally :-)